# Excel - add row to bottom with certain formatting

Tags: vba, excel

I am not sure this is even possible, but I am trying to take my excel workbook and create a button where when you click it, it will add a row to the bottom of the active workbook with certain formatting. For example, in the attached picture I would want to click the button, and a row would insert into row 14 with the same formatting at row 10. Is this possible? I have it set up now where it copies the formatting from the cell above, but it wont always be above.

Excel Question:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the code below will do what you ask:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set you Sheet above
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'find the last row with data on Column A Sheet1
ws.Range("A10:C10").Copy
'copy formating on row 10, amend range as required
ws.Range("A" & LastRow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
'paste the formating into the next free row at the bottom of Column A
End Sub
```